# FormArray dynamic dropdowns data is not loading properly

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

Unable to load selected country states data using FormArray Index. While passing the country code to fetch data, it keeps calling the API's.

Here the try,

```
<form [formGroup]='formName'>
              <div formArrayName="controllerArray" class="ui-g ui-g-12 ui-g-nopad " >
                <div  class="ui-g  ui-g-12 ui-g-nopad " *ngFor="let item of formName.controls.controllerArray.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">  
                  <div class="ui-md-4">                   
                    <label class="mandatory"
                  >{{ labels["STATE_OF_INCORPORATION_FILE_NUMBER"] }}
                  <span class="colon"></span>
                </label>           

                <select formControlName="select1" class="ui-inputtext"> 
                  <option>--Select--</option>
                  <option *ngFor="let c of countryOptions" [ngValue]="c.value">{{c.label}}</option>
                 
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="ui-md-4">
                <label class="lbl-hidden"> State </label>
                <select formControlName="select2" class="ui-inputtext"> 
                  <option>--Select--</option>
                  <option *ngFor="let b of getRelevantStates(item.controls.select1.value)" [ngValue]="b.value">{{b.label}}</option>
                 
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="ui-md-3">
                <label class="lbl-hidden"> comments  </label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  pInputText
                  class="form-control"
                  formControlName="input" />
                </div>
                <div class="ui-md-1">
                  <label class="lbl-hidden"> State </label>
                  <br/>
                  <button (click)='removeInput(i)'  style="min-width: auto;"  pButton icon="fa fa-minus"></button>
                </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
            
            <button class="add-remove-btn" pButton (click)='addInput()' icon="fa fa-plus"></button>
```

**TS**

```
getRelevantStates(countryId){
var states = [];
   this.serviceName.getStates(countryId).subscribe((res) => {
     return res[0].results;
    }
```

}

**Issue**
[image]

**Expected is**

States should be loaded based selected country in each row.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your scripts and check how it work, but I think enough add async pipe to your html:

```
<option *ngFor="let b of (getRelevantStates(item.controls.select1.value) | async)" [ngValue]="b.value">{{b.label}}</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to move that function call from html to ngOnInit or any other lifecycle event and use a variable to store data,

```
 *ngFor="let item of collection"
```

Angular call change detection for the component periodically. If you want use your current method, use change detection strategy.